# How to calculate MEC90 or MEC95 with isotonic regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, isotonic, dose-response

Several studies calculate the minimum effective concentration (MEC), volume (MEV), or dose (MED) as MEC90 or MEC95 and base the calculation on a study by [Pace and Stylianou](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17585226/).

[One of the best description of the statistical method I read](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphar.2023.1136003/full) follows as:

> Isotonic regression with R Foundation was used to calculate the ED95
> estimate of û3 (Pace and Stylianou, 2007), which is the linearly
> interpolated dose between P* κ and P* κ+1 at the probability of Г =
> 0.95. P* κand P* κ+1indicated adjusted response rates at doses χ κ and χ κ+1, respectively. The adjusted response rate is calculated
> monotonically using the pool-adjacent-violators algorithm (PAVA),
> following which the response rate was recalculated by pooling the
> adjacent increasing and decreasing pairs. Isotonic regression is an
> adjustment of regression that limits the probability of a sequential
> dose response to be monotonic.

I used the `isoreg` function from `stats` package and `pava` function from `Iso` package both of which give the one fitted value. But I don't understand the basis of calculating MEC50, MEC90 or MEC95 since I don't see any probabilistic value in the results of the above functions.

I did the analysis with probit and logit to get the 90% or 95% estimates, but the literature beginning with Pace and Stylianou suggest the use of isotonic regression for up-and-down studies, because standard probit or logit regression is likely to produce biased estimators and no attempt should be made to extrapolate a high-quantile (95 or 99) effect dose/concentration from the median points of the tolerance distribution curve.

Can you explain me with examples how to get the dose-response curve with specific probabilities (like 50%, 90%, etc)?

The sample data is here. The first column is the concentrations, and the second column is binary response (whether the concentration succeeded or failed) given as 1 or 0:

```
structure(list(conc = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.225, 0.225, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.175, 0.175, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.1, 0.075, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.125, 
0.125, 0.1, 0.1, 0.075, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1), success = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-70L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(conc = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), success = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ";"), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x00000204388a1960>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```